# Fullpage scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, smooth-scrolling, debouncing

I would need to implement a smooth full page scrolling. I already did it on this page:

http://superhostitel.cz/sluzby

**But when I scroll with wheel more, it will scroll over more pages. Please, how can I set to scroll only one page?**

My code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var divs = $('.service');
    var dir = 'up'; // wheel scroll direction
    var div = 0; // current div
    $(document.body).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            dir = 'down';
        } else {
            dir = 'up';
        }
        // find currently visible div :
        div = -1;
        divs.each(function(i){
            if (div<0 && ($(this).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop())) {
                div = i;
            }
        });
        if (dir == 'up' && div > 0) {
            div--;
        }
        if (dir == 'down' && div < divs.length) {
            div++;
        }
        //console.log(div, dir, divs.length);
        $('html,body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: divs.eq(div).offset().top
        }, 800);
        return false;
    });
    $(window).resize(function () {
        $('html,body').scrollTop(divs.eq(div).offset().top);
    });
});
```

Comment: Your website looks great. There is a ready great solution out there to have a fullpage view and works great on scrolling: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js also you could try using a debounce function for the mousewheel event https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Comment: Seems to me that you need to implement a timer delay during which further scroll events will be canceled.

Comment: Do you guys have any idea to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a guard to prevent your handler running more than once at a time, raise the flag when starting function execution, reset it when the animation is over.

Something along these lines should work (didn't test it but you should get the idea):

```
var running = false;
var handler = function (e) {
    if (running) {
        return;
    }
    running = true;
    if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
        dir = 'down';
    } else {
        dir = 'up';
    }
    // find currently visible div :
    div = -1;
    divs.each(function(i){
        if (div<0 && ($(this).offset().top >= $(window).scrollTop())) {
            div = i;
        }
    });
    if (dir == 'up' && div > 0) {
        div--;
    }
    if (dir == 'down' && div < divs.length) {
        div++;
    }
    //console.log(div, dir, divs.length);
    $('html,body').stop().animate(
        { scrollTop: divs.eq(div).offset().top }, // properties
        800,                                      // duration
        "swing",                                  // easing (needed to use 4th argument)
        function(){ running = false; }            // animation complete callback
    );

    return false;
};

$(document.body).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', handler );
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrea!  But it probably don't working. Could you catch mystake? I am beginner :/

Comment: No mate I can't do your job for you... What errors are you getting? If you understood the idea it shouldn't be hard to implement.

Comment: var divs was not defined... I solved it, thank you very much. I didn't realized that I can look in debug

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in another way:

1. Define max pages (fe) 10 pages.
2. You can pick the actual page, begin from 1 (not 0 for comfortable coding)
3. Disable normall scroll.
4. When scroll is called and the destination not extends max pages and decends minimum page(not enter #0 page) - scroll
5. Dynamically detect the window resize.
6. Have a nice day.
7. If you wanna some scrolling on specific element - I recommend you [this](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

NOTE: Use setInterval(f, 1000/60) for animation that takes user to the multiply of clientHeight and actual page.

Comment: Thank you for recommendations, but I don't really know how to implement it :/.